# Google app script publish require CASA verification after initial OAuth verification. Is there any way to avoid it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have completed initial OAuth verification process for the scopes I have been using in the app. (see scopes detail below).

Now Google verification team is requesting CASA verification process as you can see in email screenshot attached too. So getting to my question, is this verification requested because I am using **external_request** scope? or there is any other reason behind it?

I published another app too with same scopes except **drive** and **external_request** scopes and it's successfully published. Thats why I am asking that some scope could be responsible for it.

**Project OAuth Scopes
5 Scopes Requested**

See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Sheets spreadsheetshttps://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Connect to an external service  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Display and run third-party web content in prompts and sidebars inside Google applications  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui

See, edit, create, and delete all your Google Docs documents    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents

[image]

Comment: The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope is a restricted scope and will trigger a security assessment. If you can refactor your add-on to use a non restricted scopes you should be able to avoid the security assessment.

Comment: Thanks @TheAddonDepot the issue was in this scope, you are right. I am changing this scope for now to drive.readonly scope.

Comment: Hi @TheAddonDepot I changed this scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.read-only` but I still get this CASA tire 2 verification email. So I want to confirm that this is the scope that is triggering the verification?

Comment: @UmarAbdullah See https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#restricted-scopes&zippy=%2Ccan-my-tier-change%2Cdrive-api `readOnly` is also a restricted scope. Look into Google picker for `drive.file` scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [TheAddonDepot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6586255/theaddondepot) mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76389921/google-app-script-publish-require-casa-verification-after-initial-oauth-verifica/76404648#comment134709669_76389921), it was the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope that triggered the security assessment. Instead I will try to use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope for now. It was also confirmed when I emailed google about this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before I continue I would like to clarify that I have no more information than the one found publicly so I don't want this answer to come across as nothing more than mere speculation which is the best we can do in these situations as I'm sure Google will not provide us with a specific list of criteria for this.

However, based on [this help center article](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Ccan-my-tier-change) it seems like you might be up to something, here is what the article says about the reasons why your particular application has to go through the CASA verification:

[image: Google help center]

Although the information is vague (and I believe that is 100% intended) I believe that the fact that your application requires full access to all sheets and that it connects to a external service would be considered an "internal risk" as Google evaluators might consider that you could potentially be stealing and/or modifying user data without their permission as they might not be sure what exactly does the external service does.

Maybe removing the external service would help, if that is an option I would definitely suggest giving that a go, if the way the Sheets data is processed is clear on the code the additional code verification might not be needed, if this is not possible maybe showing documentation about the external service to Google might help a little although I would believe that if security is what they are after they might still ask you to go through the verification as they wouldn't have a way to know for a fact that the third party service does what they claim.

Once again I would like to clarify that this is just an educated guess, maybe the code is deemed to complex to understand or maybe there is something about the external service Google already knows that makes them not too trustworthy but I hope that the article I shared would be useful for you when making decisions about how to structure your code or which scopes to request.

Best of luck!